# How to write an unit test for a create bucket operation

Tags: python, unit-testing

```
def create_bucket(bucket_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)
    print('Bucket {} created'.format(bucket.name))
```

I am new to the python and test cases. Can you please some one help one test case for above condition?